# Air Mobile App -debug

Tags: air

I have finished developing a mobile app using AIR and whenever I run on device the name of the app always has -debug in the name. Will this be automatically removed when I submit to Apple/Android markets?

Thanks

Comment: How exactly are you publishing your app? i.e. what settings and what kind of device?

Comment: Device is iPad and I have the default AS3/Air settings

Comment: Are you using Flash Pro, Flash Builder or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realise there was an export release build button!